# SQLlite Database version number error

Tags: android, database, sqlite, version-numbering

Im get the following logcat error when I run my program regarding the db version number

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 2 to 1
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Right now, your app has a database with schema version 2. As the error indicates, you are trying to downgrade to schema version 1, which apparently is not supported.

You are welcome to uninstall your app, thereby deleting the existing database, then install it again (e.g., run it from your IDE).

However, I would recommend that you sit back and consider *why* your existing database has a higher version number than your code is requesting, as that is an unusual state to get into.

Comment: ... and, btw, the schema version is the number passed as the 4th argument to the SQLiteOpenHelper constructor...